# Programmatically adding UILabels and UIButtons to UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uilabel

My goal is to programmatically create multiple UILabels and UIButtons followed by programmatically creating and inserting them into a UIScrollView.

I am operating within the following class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

I have first created my scrollView shown below.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createTitleBar()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView
    createUpperTabs()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView
    createLowerNavBars()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView

    for _ in 0...10 {
        createTemplate() //This function consists of nested functions that creates labels and buttons that are then added to the scrollView
    }

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: currentStackY)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
```

After creating the labels and buttons, I add the views individually to the scrollView with following statement 
`self.scrollView.addSubview(UILabel or UIButton Name)`.

Here are some snippets showing how I am creating my UILabel and UIButton.

```
            let titleHeader = UILabel()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(titleHeader)
        currentStackY += 8
        titleHeader.backgroundColor = .gray
        titleHeader.text = headerTitle
        titleHeader.font = UIFont(name: buttonFont, size: buttonFontSize)
        let labelWidth = titleHeader.intrinsicContentSize.width + 16
        titleHeader.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(titleHeader)
            make.width.equalTo(titleHeader)
            make.top.equalTo(currentStackY)
            make.left.equalTo(view).offset(8)
        }
```

as well as

```
            for i in 0...chiefComplaintArray.count - 1 {
            let btn = UIButton()
            chiefComplaintButton.append(btn)
            buttonDictionary[chiefComplaintButton[i]] = numberButtonPressed
            chiefComplaintButton[i].setTitle(chiefComplaintArray[i], for: .normal)
            chiefComplaintButton[i].setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            chiefComplaintButton[i].titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: buttonFont, size: buttonFontSize)
            chiefComplaintButton[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            chiefComplaintButton[i].sizeToFit()
            let buttonWidth = chiefComplaintButton[i].frame.width + 10
            let buttonHeight = chiefComplaintButton[i].frame.height + 5

            if i == 0 {
                currentStackX = 20
                currentStackY += 5
            } else if (currentStackX + buttonWidth) > screenSize.width {
                currentStackX = 20
                currentStackY += buttonHeight + 5
            }

            chiefComplaintButton[i].frame = CGRect(x: currentStackX, y: currentStackY, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

            currentStackX += chiefComplaintButton[i].frame.width + 5

            if i == chiefComplaintArray.count - 1 {
                currentStackY += chiefComplaintButton[i].frame.height
            }
            self.scrollView.addSubview(chiefComplaintButton[i])

            chiefComplaintButton[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
```

I used similar statements to add all of the created content to the scrollView.  I have modeled my UIScrollView after other solutions in the stacks as well as other online references.  Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

I have subsequently tried

```
            let titleHeader = UILabel()
        scrollView.addSubview(titleHeader)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        currentStackY += 8
        titleHeader.backgroundColor = .gray
        titleHeader.text = headerTitle
        titleHeader.font = UIFont(name: buttonFont, size: buttonFontSize)
        let labelWidth = titleHeader.intrinsicContentSize.width + 16
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Which method is the crashing code in? Are you sure it's being called after `viewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: Please update code snippet,  Not the screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is you are initializing your `scrollView` after you are calling the method in which you are getting crash,because at that time your `scrollView` is nil.

You need to call your method after

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

**Edit**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for _ in 0...10 {
        createTemplate() //This function consists of nested functions that creates labels and buttons that are then added to the scrollView
    }

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: currentStackY)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    createTitleBar()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView
    createUpperTabs()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView
    createLowerNavBars()  //Function that creates fixed buttons and labels not included in scrollView
}
```

Also from here

```
    let titleHeader = UILabel()
    scrollView.addSubview(titleHeader)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    currentStackY += 8
    titleHeader.backgroundColor = .gray
    titleHeader.text = headerTitle
    titleHeader.font = UIFont(name: buttonFont, size: buttonFontSize)
    let labelWidth = titleHeader.intrinsicContentSize.width + 16
```

remove this

```
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: You are correct with respect to the error type.  I updated by question with the code you suggested and posted it above.  Still no luck.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and am still getting the same error.  I see what you are doing and agree that it is the way to go.  I think that I am just going to scrap and rewrite.  I would love to hear if you have any other suggestions.  Thanks